# SP.RequestExecutor is not a constructor

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-rest-api

I use sharepoint online, I have a problem whe I load my page.
I want to show a list with Rest/Api but I have this message : TypeError: SP.RequestExecutor is not a constructor

I think scripts is not loaded, how I can do ?

Comment: Can you please post the code that you are using?

Comment: Why don't You mark achehab's answer as answer)

Answer (score 1):

You can find how to load and use SP.RequestExecutor on [this link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/fp179927.aspx) (which i will not mention here).

Another way to load it though is the following:

Make sure your app has "sp.js" registered as such:

```
<asp:Content ContentPlaceHolderID="PlaceHolderAdditionalPageHead" runat="server">
    <SharePoint:ScriptLink Name="sp.js" runat="server" OnDemand="true" LoadAfterUI="true" Localizable="false" />
    <!-- other scripts / styles here -->
</asp:Content>
```

To load the SP.RequestExecutor:

```
ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(function () {
    var scriptbase = _spPageContextInfo.siteAbsoluteUrl + "/_layouts/15/";

    // Load the js files and continue to the successHandler
    $.getScript(scriptbase + "SP.RequestExecutor.js", function () {
        console.log("request executor is now loaded");
        // Logic here
    });
}, "sp.js");
```

Answer (score 1):

Add reference to your aspx or html page

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/_layouts/15/SP.RequestExecutor.js"></script>
```